# process PHP without leaving page FUNCTION onsubmit="loadXMLdoc()"

Tags: php, javascript, forms, onsubmit

HOW do i get this to work

> onsubmit

, instead of

> onclick with a button?

I have a form:

```
    <form id="form"> 
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="iput" placeholder="jane@doe.com" reguired="required"/>
    <input type="button" id="nbut" onclick="loadXMLDoc()" value="NEXT">
    </form>
```

the button works fine to call and process the javascript:

```
function loadXMLDoc() {

 var xmlhttp; 
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)   {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari   
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else {
   // code for IE6, IE5   
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

 } 
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()   {   
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {      
       document.getElementById('response').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
       document.getElementById('step1').style.display = "none";
       document.getElementById('step2').style.display = "block";
     }   
 }

 var em = document.getElementById('email'); 
 var em1 = em.value;

 xmlhttp.open("GET","bin/process.php?email="+em1,true); 
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

This only works with a button onclick, I can not get it to work onsubmit and don't know why..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onsubmit` is a `<form>` element event.

You could very simply remove the `onclick` attribute from the button and change your form to

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="loadXMLDoc(); return false;">
```

The `return false` prevents the default event handler (form submission) from executing.

Comment: Thank you for explaining return false!

Answer (score 1):

When using onsubmit you should also return false:

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="loadXMLDoc(); return false;">
```